# How does one generate an Xcode project or add an iOS extension to a .Net MAUI iOS project?

Tags: .net, xcode, visual-studio, maui, apple-watch

I know MAUI and .net doesn't directly support app extensions such as Apple Watch or Vision Pro extensions but I would like to add these to my app. I believe for Xamarin, we were able to export as an Xcode project and then load that in Xcode and then code the extension natively to add it on. Is that possible with .net or MAUI so that I can add an Apple Watch or Vision OS extension to my iOS app?

Edit:
Found this which is an example of what I'm looking for with combining Xamarin.iOS with a separate Swift component but this is for Xamarin instead of .Net.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios14/#embedded-widgetkit-support

Comment: In Xamairn.Ios, you can click the Main.storyboard file to load the project in Xcode.
But .NET Maui does not support this function up to now.  About the support for Apple Watch or Vision OS in MAUI, you can refer to [MAUI Wear OS/Watch OS Support](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/1144).

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Extend-.NET-MAUI-application-with-iOS-Extensions/

Comment: @GeraldVersluis This method relies on Xamarin which loses support this year I believe and requires that Xamarin converted the app extension. I'm looking more of a way to combine the .net app created with native xcode code.

Comment: Yes, [Xamarin support will end on May 1, 2024](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin)